# Raid 5 XFS missing superblock

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, raid, nas

Yesterday I found (the hard way) that my APC battery had failed; After a power loss at home I had to power up my computer and NAS (raid 5 XFS on Debian). The computer was fine however the I was unable to mount my raid (md127) with the message "mount: /dev/md127: can't read superblock". I tried to re-assemble the raid and found that one of the drives was not added saying "possibly out of date". I do have a backup of my files but would loose some recent work that I rather avoid at all cost.

Can anyone help with fixes I can try before rebuild/reload.

Thanks

dmesg (after reboot)

```
    root@silo:~# dmesg
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.0-4-kirkwood (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 Debian 3.2.54-2
[    0.000000] CPU: Feroceon 88FR131 [56251311] revision 1 (ARMv5TE), cr=00053977
[    0.000000] CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine: QNAP TS-41x
[    0.000000] Ignoring unrecognised tag 0x41000403
[    0.000000] Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 131072
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0443abc, node_mem_map c04aa000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1024 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 130048 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/ram initrd=0xa00000,0x900000 ramdisk=34816
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 512MB = 512MB total
[    0.000000] Memory: 505764k/505764k available, 18524k reserved, 0K highmem
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xe0800000 - 0xfe800000   ( 480 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xe0000000   ( 512 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc03e757c   (3966 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc03e8000 - 0xc040c000   ( 144 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc040c000 - 0xc0446820   ( 235 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0446844 - 0xc04a9ed8   ( 398 kB)
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:114
[    0.000000] sched_clock: 32 bits at 200MHz, resolution 5ns, wraps every 21474ms
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    7.582962] Calibrating delay loop... 1980.82 BogoMIPS (lpj=9904128)
[    7.642708] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    7.642809] Security Framework initialized
[    7.642876] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
[    7.643160] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    7.643192] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    7.643218] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    7.643234] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    7.643248] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    7.643260] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    7.643282] Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
[    7.643360] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    7.644359] devtmpfs: initialized
[    7.645658] print_constraints: dummy: 
[    7.645867] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    7.646460] Kirkwood: MV88F6282-Rev-A1, TCLK=200000000.
[    7.646488] Feroceon L2: Enabling L2
[    7.646523] Feroceon L2: Cache support initialised.
[    7.646927] initial MPP regs: 01112222 43303311 33330004 33003333 00000033 00000000 00000000
[    7.646944]   final MPP regs: 11112222 43303311 33330004 33003333 00000033 00000000 00000000
[    7.677448] Kirkwood PCIe port 0: 
[    7.677456] link up
[    7.677466] Kirkwood PCIe port 1: 
[    7.677472] link up
[    7.677495] PCI: bus0 uses PCIe port 0
[    7.677600] pci 0000:00:00.0: [11ab:6282] type 0 class 0x000580
[    7.677616] pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf1000000-0xf10fffff 64bit pref]
[    7.677625] pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 18: [mem 0x00000000-0x1fffffff]
[    7.677648] pci 0000:00:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    7.677680] pci 0000:00:01.0: [11ab:7042] type 0 class 0x000100
[    7.677701] pci 0000:00:01.0: reg 10: [mem 0x14000000-0x140fffff 64bit]
[    7.677715] pci 0000:00:01.0: reg 18: [io  0x0000-0x00ff]
[    7.677802] PCI: bus0: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    7.677962] PCI: bus1 uses PCIe port 1
[    7.678058] pci 0000:01:00.0: [11ab:6282] type 0 class 0x000580
[    7.678071] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf1000000-0xf10fffff 64bit pref]
[    7.678080] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 18: [mem 0x00000000-0x1fffffff]
[    7.678100] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    7.678135] pci 0000:01:01.0: [1b6f:7023] type 0 class 0x000c03
[    7.678162] pci 0000:01:01.0: reg 10: [mem 0x98000000-0x98007fff 64bit]
[    7.678252] pci 0000:01:01.0: supports D1 D2
[    7.678258] pci 0000:01:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot
[    7.678297] PCI: bus1: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    7.678477] pci 0000:01:01.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xe8000000-0xe8007fff 64bit]
[    7.678506] pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xe0000000-0xe00fffff 64bit]
[    7.678528] pci 0000:00:01.0: BAR 2: assigned [io  0x1000-0x10ff]
[    7.679667] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    7.679959] vgaarb: loaded
[    7.680349] Switching to clocksource orion_clocksource
[    7.690414] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    7.690572] IP route cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    7.690992] TCP established hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    7.691386] TCP bind hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    7.691585] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 16384 bind 16384)
[    7.691597] TCP reno registered
[    7.691608] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    7.691633] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    7.691785] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    7.691879] PCI: CLS 32 bytes, default 32
[    7.691983] Unpacking initramfs...
[    7.946017] Freeing initrd memory: 9216K
[    7.946050] NetWinder Floating Point Emulator V0.97 (double precision)
[    7.946470] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[    7.946517] type=2000 audit(0.350:1): initialized
[    7.947373] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[    7.947446] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    7.947533] JFFS2 version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  \xffffffc2\xffffffa9\xffffffa9 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    7.947762] msgmni has been set to 1005
[    7.948866] alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
[    7.948960] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
[    7.948982] io scheduler noop registered
[    7.948991] io scheduler deadline registered
[    7.949032] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    7.949114] mv_xor_shared mv_xor_shared.0: Marvell shared XOR driver
[    7.949144] mv_xor_shared mv_xor_shared.1: Marvell shared XOR driver
[    7.980403] mv_xor mv_xor.0: Marvell XOR: ( xor cpy )
[    8.020400] mv_xor mv_xor.1: Marvell XOR: ( xor fill cpy )
[    8.060399] mv_xor mv_xor.2: Marvell XOR: ( xor cpy )
[    8.100399] mv_xor mv_xor.3: Marvell XOR: ( xor fill cpy )
[    8.100655] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 2 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    8.120990] serial8250.0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xf1012000 (irq = 33) is a 16550A
[    8.141137] serial8250.1: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xf1012100 (irq = 34) is a 16550A
[    8.142217] m25p80 spi0.0: m25p128 (16384 Kbytes)
[    8.142241] Creating 6 MTD partitions on "spi_flash":
[    8.142256] 0x000000000000-0x000000080000 : "U-Boot"
[    8.142867] 0x000000200000-0x000000400000 : "Kernel"
[    8.143452] 0x000000400000-0x000000d00000 : "RootFS1"
[    8.144041] 0x000000d00000-0x000001000000 : "RootFS2"
[    8.144629] 0x000000080000-0x0000000c0000 : "U-Boot Config"
[    8.145205] 0x0000000c0000-0x000000200000 : "NAS Config"
[    8.145975] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    9.150392] rtc-mv rtc-mv: internal RTC not ticking
[    9.150482] i2c /dev entries driver
[    9.153922] rtc-s35390a 0-0030: rtc core: registered rtc-s35390a as rtc0
[    9.154009] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    9.154064] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    9.154550] TCP cubic registered
[    9.154566] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    9.154587] Registering the dns_resolver key type
[    9.154622] Gating clock of unused units
[    9.154627] before: 0x00cfc1dd
[    9.154631]  after: 0x00cfc1cd
[    9.154929] registered taskstats version 1
[    9.155870] rtc-s35390a 0-0030: setting system clock to 2019-06-10 16:07:44 UTC (1560182864)
[    9.155925] Initializing network drop monitor service
[    9.156481] Freeing init memory: 144K
[    9.200775] udevd[51]: starting version 175
[    9.329489] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    9.329577] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    9.379767] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    9.381155] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    9.381222] orion-ehci orion-ehci.0: Marvell Orion EHCI
[    9.381278] orion-ehci orion-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    9.410432] orion-ehci orion-ehci.0: irq 19, io mem 0xf1050000
[    9.430416] orion-ehci orion-ehci.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    9.430495] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    9.430511] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    9.430527] usb usb1: Product: Marvell Orion EHCI
[    9.430537] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.0-4-kirkwood ehci_hcd
[    9.430549] usb usb1: SerialNumber: orion-ehci.0
[    9.430913] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.430936] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    9.475361] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    9.478808] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
[    9.479553] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    9.479572] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[    9.750415] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using orion-ehci
[    9.901745] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
[    9.901770] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    9.901784] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    9.903065] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    9.903379] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[   10.180641] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using orion-ehci
[   10.291245] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5571
[   10.291269] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   10.291285] usb 1-1.2: Product: Cruzer Fit
[   10.291294] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[   10.291304] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 4C532000061020104340
[   10.292868] scsi0 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[   11.291688] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Fit       1.22 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   11.303400] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
[   11.304759] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[   11.304776] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[   11.305381] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   11.312516]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 < sda5 >
[   11.315754] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   11.724933] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   12.795936] udevd[301]: starting version 175
[   13.047621] xhci_hcd 0000:01:01.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   13.047680] xhci_hcd 0000:01:01.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[   13.047934] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   13.047951] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   13.047966] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   13.047977] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.0-4-kirkwood xhci_hcd
[   13.047988] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:01.0
[   13.048273] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[   13.048280] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[   13.048388] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   13.048416] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   13.048578] xhci_hcd 0000:01:01.0: xHCI Host Controller
[   13.048606] xhci_hcd 0000:01:01.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[   13.048663] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[   13.048679] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   13.048694] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   13.048704] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.2.0-4-kirkwood xhci_hcd
[   13.048716] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:01:01.0
[   13.048950] xHCI xhci_add_endpoint called for root hub
[   13.048956] xHCI xhci_check_bandwidth called for root hub
[   13.049059] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   13.049083] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   13.206920] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[   13.250097] sata_mv 0000:00:01.0: version 1.28
[   13.250175] PCI: enabling device 0000:00:01.0 (0140 -> 0143)
[   13.250320] sata_mv 0000:00:01.0: Gen-IIE 32 slots 4 ports SCSI mode IRQ via INTx
[   13.257639] scsi1 : sata_mv
[   13.267286] scsi2 : sata_mv
[   13.272185] scsi3 : sata_mv
[   13.277046] scsi4 : sata_mv
[   13.277299] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 mmio m1048576@0xe0000000 port 0xe0022000 irq 9
[   13.277322] ata2: SATA max UDMA/133 mmio m1048576@0xe0000000 port 0xe0024000 irq 9
[   13.277340] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 mmio m1048576@0xe0000000 port 0xe0026000 irq 9
[   13.277357] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 mmio m1048576@0xe0000000 port 0xe0028000 irq 9
[   13.295691] input: gpio-keys as /devices/platform/gpio-keys/input/input0
[   13.295817] mv643xx_eth: MV-643xx 10/100/1000 ethernet driver version 1.4
[   13.295898] mv643xx_eth smi: probed
[   13.343340] mv643xx_eth_port mv643xx_eth_port.0: eth0: port 0 with MAC address 00:08:9b:cd:2a:0c
[   13.379373] mv643xx_eth_port mv643xx_eth_port.1: eth1: port 0 with MAC address 00:08:9b:cd:2a:0d
[   13.379482] sata_mv sata_mv.0: version 1.28
[   13.379594] sata_mv sata_mv.0: slots 32 ports 2
[   13.384600] scsi5 : sata_mv
[   13.392294] scsi6 : sata_mv
[   13.392492] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 irq 21
[   13.392507] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 irq 21
[   13.740400] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl F300)
[   13.780418] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   13.820488] ata1.00: ATA-9: WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0, 80.00A80, max UDMA/133
[   13.820506] ata1.00: 5860533168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   13.860435] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   13.860681] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68A 80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   13.862427] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[   13.862452] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   13.862628] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   13.862645] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   13.862718] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   13.881055]  sdb: unknown partition table
[   13.881780] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[   14.370420] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   14.410434] ata2.00: ATA-9: WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0, 80.00A80, max UDMA/133
[   14.410453] ata2.00: 5860533168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   14.450435] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   14.450680] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68A 80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   14.452327] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[   14.452352] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   14.452525] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[   14.452541] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   14.452613] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   14.472684]  sdc: unknown partition table
[   14.473385] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[   14.960416] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   15.000434] ata3.00: ATA-9: WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0, 80.00A80, max UDMA/133
[   15.000452] ata3.00: 5860533168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   15.040436] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   15.040702] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68A 80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   15.041659] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[   15.041682] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   15.041859] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[   15.041874] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   15.041946] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   15.055786]  sdd: unknown partition table
[   15.056490] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[   20.590391] ata4: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   22.810420] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   23.030435] ata4.00: ATA-9: WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0, 80.00A80, max UDMA/133
[   23.030453] ata4.00: 5860533168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[   23.070439] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   23.070705] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68A 80.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   23.071679] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[   23.071704] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[   23.071880] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[   23.071896] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[   23.071968] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   23.104791]  sde: unknown partition table
[   23.105482] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[   23.420445] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl F300)
[   23.510310] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[   23.511886] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   23.513325] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   23.513616] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   23.514241] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[   23.741259] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   23.741291] ata2: EH complete
[   23.791113] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   23.791143] ata1: EH complete
[   23.813326] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   23.813356] ata4: EH complete
[   23.813702] sd 4:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   23.840484] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   23.840514] ata3: EH complete
[   23.840935] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   24.114414] md: md127 stopped.
[   24.140437] md: bind<sdb>
[   24.143759] md: bind<sdd>
[   24.147115] md: bind<sde>
[   24.147797] md: bind<sdc>
[   24.147872] md: kicking non-fresh sdb from array!
[   24.147891] md: unbind<sdb>
[   24.147908] md: export_rdev(sdb)
[   24.181294] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[   24.183969] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[   24.230378]    arm4regs  :  1810.000 MB/sec
[   24.280378]    8regs     :  1086.000 MB/sec
[   24.330376]    32regs    :  1504.000 MB/sec
[   24.330389] xor: using function: arm4regs (1810.000 MB/sec)
[   24.580591] raid6: int32x1    122 MB/s
[   24.750506] raid6: int32x2    192 MB/s
[   24.920649] raid6: int32x4    200 MB/s
[   25.090599] raid6: int32x8    254 MB/s
[   25.090611] raid6: using algorithm int32x8 (254 MB/s)
[   25.164682] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[   25.164708] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[   25.164718] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[   25.165553] bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
[   25.165598] md/raid:md127: device sdc operational as raid disk 1
[   25.165612] md/raid:md127: device sde operational as raid disk 3
[   25.165624] md/raid:md127: device sdd operational as raid disk 2
[   25.166378] md/raid:md127: allocated 4218kB
[   25.166494] md/raid:md127: raid level 5 active with 3 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[   25.166513] RAID conf printout:
[   25.166518]  --- level:5 rd:4 wd:3
[   25.166523]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdc
[   25.166527]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd
[   25.166531]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde
[   25.166617] md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 9001374842880
[   25.187177]  md127: unknown partition table
[   25.520443] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   25.520474] ata1: EH complete
[   25.680440] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   25.680468] ata2: EH complete
[   25.880442] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   25.880470] ata3: EH complete
[   26.080441] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   26.080469] ata4: EH complete
[   26.382524] Adding 708604k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:708604k 
[   26.432970] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   26.755178] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   26.918611] loop: module loaded
[   29.190059] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, large block/inode numbers, no debug enabled
[   29.200982] SGI XFS Quota Management subsystem
[   29.202791] XFS (md127): Mounting Filesystem
[   29.481599] XFS (md127): Starting recovery (logdev: internal)
[   29.483087] XFS (md127): xlog_recover_process_data: bad clientid 0x0
[   29.483122] XFS (md127): log mount/recovery failed: error 5
[   29.483284] XFS (md127): log mount failed
[   30.517334] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   30.847360] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[   30.847389] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[   30.847399] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[   30.847409] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[   30.875393] FS-Cache: Loaded
[   30.939225] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[   30.974502] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
[   31.469829] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   34.384012] mv643xx_eth_port mv643xx_eth_port.0: eth0: link up, 1000 Mb/s, full duplex, flow control disabled
[   34.384156] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   45.070384] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Mount (after reboot)

```
root@silo:~# mount /dev/md127 /media/Silo
mount: /dev/md127: can't read superblock
```

Re-Assemble

```
root@silo:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
root@silo:~# mdadm --verbose --assemble --force /dev/md127 /dev/sdb 
/dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md127
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sde is identified as a member of /dev/md127, slot 3.
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md127 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md127 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sde to /dev/md127 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md127 as 1
mdadm: /dev/md127 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4).
```

mdadm --examine /dev/sd*

```
    root@silo:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd*
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :       497664 sectors at         2048 (type 83)
Partition[1] :     29345792 sectors at       499712 (type 83)
Partition[2] :      1417218 sectors at     29847550 (type 05)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda2.
/dev/sda3:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :      1417216 sectors at            2 (type 82)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda5.
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 614b81d3:13527af4:85ba7bee:c4249f4c
           Name : silo:Silo  (local to host silo)
  Creation Time : Tue Mar  4 12:16:53 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 8790405120 (8383.18 GiB 9001.37 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860270080 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 803eb25a:6a30a851:b58b3c26:2a8e7272

    Update Time : Sun Jun  9 15:41:15 2019
       Checksum : 37980d0f - correct
         Events : 432

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 614b81d3:13527af4:85ba7bee:c4249f4c
           Name : silo:Silo  (local to host silo)
  Creation Time : Tue Mar  4 12:16:53 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 8790405120 (8383.18 GiB 9001.37 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860270080 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 86c408cb:4803fec8:21f9b333:db9de180

    Update Time : Mon Jun 10 09:14:49 2019
       Checksum : 3b2cda06 - correct
         Events : 440

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 614b81d3:13527af4:85ba7bee:c4249f4c
           Name : silo:Silo  (local to host silo)
  Creation Time : Tue Mar  4 12:16:53 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 8790405120 (8383.18 GiB 9001.37 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860270080 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 67975b5d:8b1ca7d5:0d220e51:82842ecc

    Update Time : Mon Jun 10 09:14:49 2019
       Checksum : 42cfd5be - correct
         Events : 440

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 614b81d3:13527af4:85ba7bee:c4249f4c
           Name : silo:Silo  (local to host silo)
  Creation Time : Tue Mar  4 12:16:53 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 5860271024 (2794.40 GiB 3000.46 GB)
     Array Size : 8790405120 (8383.18 GiB 9001.37 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860270080 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fbb72f53:821b6327:ee1e9c3d:96627350

    Update Time : Mon Jun 10 09:14:49 2019
       Checksum : fb32d03d - correct
         Events : 440

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : .AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```